# Elixir/Phoenix Best way to store/represent data that needs to be accessed but will rarely change

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the app we are creating, we have customers that give us their items to make use of the services we provide. An example would be, a customer owns a book and would like to have it encased for future storage or get it checked for its condition.

We've decided to structure in this way:

**Items**

```
Name
Details
Company
embeds_many :services
```

**Services**

```
(embedded schema)
Service
Price
```

We have various services offered by different companies, so for example it would look like:

```
Company 1 {

  {Service: a,
  Price: 100},

  {Service: b,
  Price: 100},

}

Company 2 {

  {Service: c,
  Price: 100},

  {Service: d,
  Price: 100},

}
```

My question is what is the best way to represent this data, knowing that when a customer fills out a form, the values will be used to show the total price to the customer and those values will be saved as a service under each submitted item, so the data must be easily accessible.

Secondly, new services and price changes may occur, but quite rarely, maybe at the rate of once or twice a year.

We were originally considering just having a db table for the services and save the values to each item (so as not to ruin the accounting in the future should the service prices change), but is there a better way to do this to have faster access to the services data?

Comment: Why not just create a module and store the data in a file, read it in, similar to how elixir knows unicode?  That way you remove the database requirement.

Comment: You could look into ETS tables. They're an erlang feature that should do what you describe. You can then have the data queried on startup and loaded into ETS tables for access from anywhere, or through a wrapper module